# Sharing webpage posts with custom title, image, description

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What is best way to use for sharing webpage posts in your facebook group?

Lets take this as my website `mywebsite.com/news.php`
Every of my news has unique `id`.

Link  of one of my web post is `mywebsite.com/news.php?id=57`

So how do I make custom title and image when I want to share this link `mywebsite.com/news.php?id=57` ?

I tried using facebook Graph API but It did not worked for me.

How can I achive that when I paste link of my web post
 (example: `mywebsite.com/news.php?id=57` ) that It creates custom image and title for sharing based on  variables in my web post that are defined based on post `id`
Every post on my page (every id) has its own
`$title, $image, $description, $url`
and they needs to be used as title, image and url when I copy link of web post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by meta tags facebook has a tool where you can even test out the content.

Add the meta tags dynamically to your news page based on the id.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/19/arts/international/when-great-minds-dont-think-alike.html" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="When Great Minds Don’t Think Alike" />
<meta property="og:description" content="How much does culture influence creative thinking?" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://static01.nyt.com/images/2015/02/19/arts/international/19iht-btnumbers19A/19iht-btnumbers19A-facebookJumbo-v2.jpg" />
```

More details are given here :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters